# Using Flask-migrate for models in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am confused about how to use Flask-Migrate when I have multiple models. 
Basically my Flask app looks like this:

```
app
├── __init__.py
├── config.py
├── manage.py
├── migrations
├── models
│   ├── model1.py
│   ├── model2.py
├── resources
├── run.py
└── tests
```

I've [read](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions) that for each model its best to create the `db = SQLAlchemy()` object in the file and then import this db object into the app's`__init__.py` like so:

```
from models.model1 import db
db.init_app(app)
from models.model2 import db
db.init_app(app)
```

However if I do this for multiple model files, how can I add Flasks's migrate functionality, considering I can only use 1 sql alchemy object for the migrate class instantiation:

```
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

Would it be best in this case to define a single sql alchemy object in the `__init__.py` file and import that into all my models?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misread the referenced text. That talks about something completely different. That talks about keeping your `db` object separate from the `app` object (and tie the two togther in the `create_app` factory function). Creating multiple `db` objects is only complicating matters for you.

All that is needed is a **single** `db = SQLAlchemy()` object, and all the files that define models need to be imported. Usually that's done directly or indirectly via your `create_app` factory function, You need to call the `create_app()` function anyway to be able to run the `flask db` command-line tool *anyway*.

Next, you do *not* need to create a manager *either*. The `Manager` object is a hold-over from the time before the Flask project added support for scripts itself. If you are using Flask 0.12 or newer, you **don't** want to be using Flask-Script and it's manager.

So, all you need, in your `__init_.py`, is:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate


db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(f"{__name__}.config")
    app.config.from_envvar("PROJECTNAME_SETTINGS", silent=True)
    if test_config:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)

    # importing the models to make sure they are known to Flask-Migrate
    from models import models1, models2

    # any other registrations; blueprints, template utilities, commands

    return app
```

Comment: The problem here is that you cannot describe your model without db:

```
class User(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

Should i init `db` inside models package and suck it into create_app? Or i should create `db`  near create_app and pass it down to models package and initialize every model dynamically somehow?

Comment: @a0s you can create the db instance anywhere you like and import it where it is needed; I keep mine in the module with the `create_app()` factory because other Flask extensions may refer to it too, but it doesn’t really matter.